# How to implement decorator to force Python type hinting?

Tags: python, types, decorator, assert, type-hinting

I've been using type hinting as of late.  In some cases, it would be useful to force the type automatically instead of the boilerplate of `isinstance` for every type hinted variable.  It would be seamless to have a decorator that could do this but I'm not even sure if this is possible in Python.

How would one implement a decorator that forces the type hinting? For example, having the capabilities of function `g` but the syntax of function `h`.

```
def f(a:str, b:int) -> str:
    c = a * b
    return c

f("XXYYZZ", 3)
# 'XXYYZZXXYYZZXXYYZZ'
f(1, "3") # I understand why this works but was wondering if there is a way to seamlessly assert arguments types
# '3'

def g(a:str, b:int) -> str:
    assert isinstance(a, str)
    assert isinstance(b, int)

    c = a * b
    return c

g(1, "3") 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-244-c13aa517b8e9> in <module>
#      15     return c
#      16 
# ---> 17 g(1, "3")

# <ipython-input-244-c13aa517b8e9> in g(a, b)
#       9 
#      10 def g(a:str, b:int) -> str:
# ---> 11     assert isinstance(a, str)
#      12     assert isinstance(b, int)
#      13 

# AssertionError: 

@assert_types(inputs=True, outputs=False)
def h(a:str, b:int) -> str:
    c = a * b
    return c
```

Comment: You can implement this, although, there are projects that have already done the dirty work (e.g. `pydantic`). But consider *instead* of runtime type checking, just use a static type checker, e.g. `mypy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this decorator, however, like @juanpa.arrivillaga said, you are better using mypy

```
def asset_types(func):
    def wrapper(a,b, *args):
       assert isinstance(a, str)
       assert isinstance(b, int)
       func(a,b)
    return wrapper

@asset_types
def h(a:str, b:int) -> str:
    c = a * b
    return c
```